JavaEE scheduled task wait for transaction commit
I have some Tasks which are stored in a database (MySQL). Task basically makes an API call to a remote system, which throws an exception if two Tasks try to execute concurrently.
This is the current implementation.
@Singleton
public class QueueScheduler {
    private final AtomicBoolean processing = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    @Inject
    public QueueService queueService;

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/5", persistent = false)
    @Lock(LockType.READ)
    public void tick() {
        if (processing.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
            try {
                queueService.executeNext();
            } finally {
                processing.set(false);
            }
        }
    }
}


@Dependent
public class QueueService {
    @Inject
    RetryableService retryableService;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void executeNext() {
        List<Queue> list = queueRepository.findLastIncomplete(1);

        if (list.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        retryableService.tryExecute(task);
    }
}

@Dependent
public class RetryableService {
    public final EntityManager entityManager;

    public RetryableService(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public <T extends RetryableEntity> void tryExecute(RetryableTask<T> task) {
        T entity = task.getEntity();

        entity.setLastAttemptTimestamp(new Date());
        entity.setAttemptCount(entity.getAttemptCount() + 1);

        try {
            task.run(entity);
            entity.setCompletedTimestamp(new Date());
            entity.setCompletedSuccessfully(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            entity.setCompletedSuccessfully(false);
            entity.setCompletedTimestamp(new Date());
        }

        entityManager.flush();
    }
}


@Stateless
public class QueueRepository {
    @Inject
    public EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<Queue> findLastIncomplete(int count) {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Queue> cq = cb.createQuery(Queue.class);
        Root<Queue> table = cq.from(Queue.class);
        cq.select(table);
        cq.where(cb.isNull(table.get(Queue_.completedTimestamp)));
        cq.orderBy(cb.desc(table.get(Queue_.startedTimestamp)));

        return entityManager.createQuery(cq)
            .setFirstResult(0)
            .setMaxResults(count)
            .getResultList();
    }
}

The problem is, while it works fine most of the time, sometimes the task finishes successfully (no transaction rollback), no error), but the same task is executed again by another thread. It seems that the second thread (which executes less than a second after the first is finished), doesn't have an updated entity (Queue.completedTimestamp is null), and it executes it again.
I am not entirely sure what is going on (I inherited the code), but the only idea I have is that the QueueScheduler.tick() triggers the second thread before the entity is fully persisted in the database (shouldn't flush do that?) and the second thread receives stale entity.
I've already seen EJB @Schedule wait until method completed but I am a bit confused about the transaction part on my side.

Depending on when the 2nd task does its first select establishing the database snapshot, it can read the previous state of any rows under the default repeatable read isolation level in mysql.

But shouldn't the transaction (in executeNext()) commit before returning to the QueueScheduler.tick ?
So it seems that the next tick() happens before the task data is fully persisted?
I was thinking of two options, one would be to manually schedule the next timer, the other would be to use UserTransaction and manually commit it.

You need to enable the mysql query log to see the sequence of sql statements issued as I have absolutely no clue when these complex Java classes interact with mysql. It may be worth a try to change the isolation level to read committed, which would enable future reads to read updated versions of the rows.
